# Putting a website into an app

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to simply put a website into a java (or other programming language) application. 
like an iframe kind of thing that will just display the webpage as is.

Comment: Use WebView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: You have to use webview for this..just open your webpage in your screen.

Comment: A simple [Google Search](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=JsBHU86aNrDO8gfVwoD4Ag#q=android%20convert%20website%20to%20app) would have given you [AppsGeyser](http://www.appsgeyser.com/) and [AppYet](http://www.appyet.com/). They are good even if you cannot code (_Android apps at least_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code:-

```
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) inside your application...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.You can call your web site in WebView in android.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is something like trigger.io.

This is a "website" (or web-application) wrapper for making html sites run as a native app.
It does more than that. It even offers support for using the device hardware like: GPS, Camera, ...

Link: www.trigger.io

It is not a free services, but it works well and is easy to start with.

Hope this helps